# How to pass locale to page object models?

Tags: pom

I have some tests in Cypress and I've implemented a page object model and reused some functions in all my tests. For a test, I'd like to validate some texts (that are different based on the language/country)  and run my test for different locales and languages.

How can I pass my locale/country value in the URL to all the POM functions in a clean and nonredundant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a test, I'd like to validate some texts

I wouldn't mix the responsibilities of modeling the interactions with the page (page objects) with asserting the values (responsibility of the tests). And also the part of storage of the expected values.

Let's take, for instance, this area of the StackExchange web page.

[image]

You may have a page object to represent this area, called PublicLinks

One method of this object may be *queryListOfLinks*, which for the sake of demonstration returns a list of strings with the title of each link.

(Pseudocode)

```
class PublicLinks:

   fun List<String> queryListOfLinks():
       return findAll(linkLocator).map(link -> link.getText());
```

Then, on your test, you can call this method and assert the values, but you will need to inject the locale you wish to have - for instance, using a command argument:

```
   fun test():
        val publicLinks = new PublicLinks()
        val locale = system.getArg("locale")
        val expectedValues = stringRepository.getLocale(locale).get("publicLinks")
        assert(expectedValues).equals(publicLinks.queryListOfLinks())
```

The StringRepository can be as you wish: A database adapter, a simple class that open files based on the locale name, a class that makes an HTTP call to a web service, etc.

This way, the three responsibilities are separated:

- If the web page changes, you need to change only the page object;
- If the application logic changes, you need to change only the test;
- If the method to retrieve the string values changes, you need to change only the StringRespository;

Answer (score 1):

If its page object model then the functions for getting and returning the country should be local to each page's class- similar to each page objects GoTo() function, you could implement a GetCountry() function on each needed page, or as public members of the page's class via getters and setters for easy reference.

```
public get country() {
    return cy.url().split('/') //or however you get the country from the url
}
```

and then in the test:

```
assert(myPage.country == "England")
//Code testing for language specific changes
```

Or something similar. If the country value is always in the page URL, and its a common enough need, you could add it to the browser manager class outright.